# how to calculate the cumulative sum of sequences of values

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
x <- cbind(label = c(1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,1,1),
            val = c(1,3,7,5,4,2,6,8,5,1))
 x
      label val
 [1,]     1   1
 [2,]     1   3
 [3,]     1   7
 [4,]    -1   5
 [5,]    -1   4
 [6,]     0   2
 [7,]     0   6
 [8,]    -1   8
 [9,]     1   5
[10,]     1   1
```

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of sequences of values in the `val`, but the sequence is determined by the `label` column.
That is:

1. `label` 1,1,1  cumsum `val` 1, 1+3, 1+4+7
2. `label` -1,-1  cumsum `val` -5, -5 + -4
3. if the `label` is zero then we ignore it
   and so on..

`label` can only have three values `-1`, `0`, `1`

Also I want to have a column with the last value from each cumulative sum
In the final result I would like to get a matrix like this

```
res_x <- cbind(x,
                cum_val = c(1,4,11,-5,-9,0,0,-8,5,6),
                last_cum_val = c(NA,NA,11,NA,-9,NA,NA,8,NA,6))
 
 res_x
      label val cum_val last_cum_val
 [1,]     1   1       1           NA
 [2,]     1   3       4           NA
 [3,]     1   7      11           11
 [4,]    -1   5      -5           NA
 [5,]    -1   4      -9           -9
 [6,]     0   2       0           NA
 [7,]     0   6       0           NA
 [8,]    -1   8      -8           -8
 [9,]     1   5       5           NA
[10,]     1   1       6            6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x |> 
  mutate(group = c(0, cumsum(diff(label) != 0))) |> 
  mutate(cum_val = sign(label) *  cumsum(val), .by = group) |> 
  mutate(last_cum_val = ifelse(row_number() == n(), last(cum_val), NA), .by = group)

      label val group cum_val last_cum_val
[1,]      1   1     0       1           NA
[2,]      1   3     0       4           NA
[3,]      1   7     0      11           11
[4,]     -1   5     1      -5           NA
[5,]     -1   4     1      -9           -9
[6,]      0   2     2       0           NA
[7,]      0   6     2       0            0
[8,]     -1   8     3      -8           -8
[9,]      1   5     4       5           NA
[10,]     1   1     4       6            6
```

Comment: FYI, `dplyr` now has a function `consecutive_id()` that does the `c(0, cumsum(diff(label) != 0))` for you, and is nicely flexible in that it works for non-numeric classes too.

Comment: Yes thanks, noticed this as well based on your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)

x |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  group_by(consecutive_id(label)) |>
  mutate(
    cum_val = cumsum(label * val),
    last_cum_val = ifelse(row_number() == n(), cum_val, NA)
)
# # A tibble: 10 × 5
# # Groups:   consecutive_id(label) [5]
#    label   val `consecutive_id(label)` cum_val last_cum_val
#    <dbl> <dbl>                   <int>   <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1     1     1                       1       1           NA
#  2     1     3                       1       4           NA
#  3     1     7                       1      11           11
#  4    -1     5                       2      -5           NA
#  5    -1     4                       2      -9           -9
#  6     0     2                       3       0           NA
#  7     0     6                       3       0            0
#  8    -1     8                       4      -8           -8
#  9     1     5                       5       5           NA
# 10     1     1                       5       6            6
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question

Comment: Fixed now, had to do the `group_by` first.

Comment: with advent of `consecutive_id` in `dplyr` things have become easier

Comment: Well, no more dipping in to `data.table` just to use their `rleid`.